# Are there any large cardinals that are inconsistent with ZF?

Tags: logic

[Reinhard cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal) are the largest cardinals yet defined that are consistent with ZF. This suggests that there are large cardinals that are inconsistent with ZF - are there in fact any?

Comment: The last time I checked, Reinhardt Cardinals were not known to be inconsistent with ZF. Have you come across an article or link that says otherwise?

Comment: @Piper: no; I haven't claimed that they were. I'd be *very* suprised if there are any any as they seem to be defined within the language of *ZF*; and presumably similar definitions can be made for other set theories like *NBG*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is a very facetious answer to your question; it depends what you mean by large cardinal axiom.

For instance *0-sharp* is something like a large cardinal axiom without asserting the existence of a cardinal explicitly. It's rather about sets of indiscernibles that code the construction of *L*, and is very naturally viewed as a *(Delta^1)_3* non-constructible real. However, *0-sharp* fits very nicely into the large cardinal hierarchy, so is something like a large cardinal axiom; it's a principle of *strength*.

If we're talking about principles of strength then, there is a very obvious axiom that is inconsistent with *ZF*, namely *0=1*. However, this is obviously not what you're looking for, rather you want an axiom that is in some sense "natural" or "conceivable" or "contentful" (or some other similarly philosophically problematic notion; cans of worms everywhere!), but that is inconsistent with *ZF*. Hugh Woodin and Peter Koellner have been working on thinking up such a large cardinal notion inconsistent with *ZF*; the hierarchy is roughly outlined in the Wikipedia article you cite (I would be somewhat careful of that, however; there are a couple of errors in the text). No inconsistency has yet been found, however.

Comment: This possible belongs in meta, but why on earth doesn't this forum support LaTeX?

Comment: I don't know why this forum doesn't support it, but I've edited to look a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks. Just quickly; the in Delta^1_3, the 1 is a superscript on the Delta and the 3 is a subscript. I'll edit it now (rather than Delta^(1/3) which might be a little confusing). Nice to see people interested in this stuff!

Comment: It's not a forum, and [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow/60020#60020).